# Java interface question

Tags: java, generics, interface, covariance

Let's say I have 2 interfaces, A and B:

```
public interface A {
 List<B> getBs();
}

public interface B {
}
```

and 2 classes that implement those interfaces:

```
public class AImpl implements A {

 public List<B> getBs() {
  return null;
 }

}


public class BImpl implements B {
}
```

Could it possible (maybe using generics) that my getter method returns a list of BImpl typed objects, something as:

```
public class AImpl implements A {

 public List<BImpl> getBs() {
  return null;
 }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you will need to change the interface declaration to this:

```
public interface A {
 List<? extends B> getBs();
}
```

However, if you want clients to know which implementation type you use, things will get more complicated:

```
public interface A<C extends B> {
     List<C> getBs();
}

public class AImpl implements A<Bimpl>{
     public List<Bimpl> getBs();
}
```

Comment: This compiles: public interface A<C extends B>.

Comment: @andy true, I used the method syntax, not the type syntax. Fixed, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Only if you can change the definition of `A.getBs()` method to:

```
List<? extends B> getBs();
```

Answer (score 3):

No, because generic types are not covariant.

`List<BImpl>` is not a subclass of `List<B>`.

Part of the contract of the method in interface A is that it returns a `List<B>`.

```
public interface A {
 List<B> getBs();
}
```

A `List<BImpl>` does not support that contract. For example, a recipient expecting a `List<B>` might try to add to the list instances of other types of B -- say, `BImpl2` and `BImpl3`.

A `List<B>` containing only BImpl's would support the contract.